# Attackability of one-time MAC when using block mode

Tags: block-cipher, mac, one-time-pad

Consider an encrypted message `m` which is encrypted with AES-CBC, so in addition to the message there is an `IV` supplied initially. If I understand correctly the `IV` and afterwards the prior ciphertext is used, because if wasn't used, a listening attacker could gather information about the secret key `s`.
We want to add a authentication code (MAC) to the package, however we are quite limited with the amount of bytes we have for the MAC.

Our initial idea was to use `s` to generate a MAC of length `s/2`. If this would be used on more than one package **could the attacker gain information from it?** As far as I understand it's the same problem as using a one-time-pad again and again.

**If this is a problem would a possible solution to this be to XOR the message with the IV (or prior ciphertexts) and then generate the MAC with `s`?**

If this doesn't solve the problem, is there any other authentication mechanism we could use, where we can decide the length of the authentication code.

*Note: we already spent thoughts on the security of short MACs and don't think it's a problem in our particular scenario.*

Comment: The standard approach if you have less than 16 bytes per packet for authentication would be to take a PRF-based MAC (like AES-OMAC or AES-CMAC or keyed Blake{1,2,3} or KMAC or HMAC) and truncate the output to whatever size you have.

Comment: I have to admit I'm a bit confused by your question (which is why the previous comment is only tangentially related). Is the construction the all-bold paragraph is suggesting effectively MAC(key,IV XOR Message) or MAC(key, IV XOR Ciphertext) or something different? When you say your MAC is of length s/2 you mean that it's half as long as s and not half the _value_ of s as the length? Also from the question it would appear that you perhaps not realize that a MAC is a function that takes a "message" and a key and outputs a short-ish value that can be used to integrity-check the message?

Comment: Can you please describe the attack you have in mind on your proposed simple MAC that would break it on key-reuse? (this would probably help us understand the construction more you're suggesting)

Comment: I will try to reformulate the question tomorrow, but your initial comment is already helpful.